# None of DatetimeIndex are in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was trying to plot my MACD Line with date, but seems to face error of none of Datetimeindex are in column, below are my codes

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime as dt
%matplotlib inline
plt.style = 'ggplot'

stock = "SPY"
Start_date = '2019-1-1'
End_date = dt.datetime.today()
Quick_EMA = 12
Slow_EMA = 26
df = web.DataReader(stock,'yahoo',Start_date,End_date)
df['12EMA'] = df['Adj Close'].ewm(span = Quick_EMA, min_periods = Quick_EMA).mean()
df['26EMA'] = df['Adj Close'].ewm(span = Slow_EMA, min_periods = Slow_EMA).mean()
df['MACDLine'] = df['12EMA'] - df['26EMA']
y = df['MACDLine']
x = df.index
df.plot(x,y)

KeyError: "None of [DatetimeIndex(['2018-12-31', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-04',\n               '2019-01-07', '2019-01-08', '2019-01-09', '2019-01-10',\n               '2019-01-11', '2019-01-14',\n               ...\n               '2020-05-15', '2020-05-18', '2020-05-19', '2020-05-20',\n               '2020-05-21', '2020-05-22', '2020-05-26', '2020-05-27',\n               '2020-05-28', '2020-05-29'],\n              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', length=356, freq=None)] are in the [columns]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is specified like this.

```
df.plot(y='MACDLine')

df['MACDLine'].plot()
```

[image]